# overloading methods that have no parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 implementations of a method that should do almost the same thing on both implementations.

The first one binds the ASP GridView control on the page with the selected data:

```
// Bind the GridView with the data.
private void LoadArticles()
{
    List<ListArticleViewModel> model = new List<ListArticleViewModel>();

    // Query the database and get the data.

    GridView1.DataSource = model;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

The second implementation is to return a list with the same data as an Enumerable:

```
private IEnumerable<ListArticleViewModel> LoadArticles()
{
    List<ListArticleViewModel> model = new List<ListArticleViewModel>();

    // Query the database and get the data.

    return model.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Clearly the overloading doesn't work here because the signatures don't differentiate on return type.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

> A return type of a method is not part of the signature of the method for the purposes of method overloading.

That leaves me in a bit of a quandary since I don't actually need parameters for this so how would I overload this and get it working?

Should I rather just use a different name for the method?

Comment: Or you use a different name or you use a dummy parameter, which I think it's worse than a different name.

Edit I like the way that @DavidArno explain it ;-)

Comment: "*Should I rather just use a different name for the method?*". Yes. They do different things, so give them different names, that reflect what they do.

Comment: Use different names because they are doing different things. And I would recommend putting the database query in a different method (and even better class) and renaming your method into something like `SetData`and then you will recognize that you just need one method for doing this ;)

Comment: If you call `LoadArticles()` in your code what would you expect to run? - You want to name them differently so you can call each one when you need it.

Comment: @RyanSearle the logical inference of `var this = LoadArticles();` would be that it calls the overload that has a return type whereas simply using `LoadArticles()` should execute the one that doesn't... Is that a particular reason why this isn't the case?

Comment: The fact that you can call `LoadArticles()` and ignore its return type in a strongly-type language like `c#` is reason enough for it not to be allowed.

Comment: My common rule: Name the methods that it will describe what they are doing. So I would end up here in *BindGridViewWithArticles* and *GetArticles*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloading is, from a technical point of view, irrelevant as to how the application works. There is no real reason for wanting several different methods to carry the same name, with the sole exception of **developer readability**.

You can name these methods `Superman()` and `Batman()`, and it wouldn't change how the application works. The names are irrelevant as far as the compiler cares.

So the short answer to your question is: **Don't give those methods the same name!**
Especially if they do different things, it only adds to the confusion by giving them the same name.

Comment: @Rahul: Tit for tat is really childish, you know.

Comment: @Rahul since my question was `how would I overload this and get it working?` and Flater's answer is, basically, "you don't - give them different names", it pretty much solves the issue for me. There are more questions raised by this but that's for another post.

Answer (score 0):

As you know what method overloading is and how they should be written in OOP language like C#. The problem you are creating for yourself is due to improper use of OOP. One of the thing that OOP says is one method should perform one and only thing.

But you are doing 2 things in your method

```
private void LoadArticles()
{
   //Load data
    List<ListArticleViewModel> model = new List<ListArticleViewModel>();

    //Bind loaded Data
    GridView1.DataSource = model;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Clearly you are doing 2 things loading and binding in one method. OOP doesn't suggest it. Instead you should only return data from that method

```
public IEnumerable<ListArticleViewModel> LoadArticles()
{
    List<ListArticleViewModel> model = new List<ListArticleViewModel>();

    // Query the database and get the data.

    return model.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Now you can use above public method anywhere. (You can change access modifier if you want considering your requirement)

Now with above implementation you can call that method as

```
var dataSource = new Article().LoadArticles();
GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I assume your LoadArticles method is written inside Article class which is inside a global namespace as your calling code written in.

If you don't like this approach then you can not solve your problem by using method overloading approach too with same return type and no input parameters for both method. Instead you can rename one of the method and you are ready to go.

Comment: Downvoted for the nonsense statement, "*...improper use of OOP...*"

Comment: @RyanSearle can you justify why the above implementation won't compile

Comment: @BhubanShrestha unless `Article()` in your implementation is a value type (it probably isn't, lets be honest), you'd need to instantiate it first otherwise you're going to end up with a NullReferenceException on the assignment of `dataSource`

Comment: @Ortund I have stated (assumed) Article class contains LoadArticles method and Article class is inside global namespace (has same namespace) as of caller class namespace.

Comment: perhaps the 2 methods with the same name and same parameters.

Comment: Could you explain what this has anything to do with OOP?

Comment: @RyanSearle with OP approach you can think as he is trying to write two method in a class one for binding directly to control and one method for returning data for something else purpose. Isn't this OOP.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha: This problem is not related to the general use of classes, inheritance, interface implementation, polymorphism, ... So no, this is not OOP. Obviously, since the poster is making use of C#, the problem is presented within an OOP code base; but that has nothing to do with the problem at hand. This exact same problem could occur in C or C++, neither of which are (inherently) OOP.